# Why does my slideshow not showing at the beginning?

Tags: javascript, html

I slideshow work whit I press the arrows but it give me this error when it loads

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
>       at showSlides (gallery.js:24)
>       at gallery.js:2

This is my code 
Javascript

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
     slideIndex = 1
  } 
  if (n < 1) {
   slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because the element `slides[slideIndex-1]` does not exist, can be because `document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides")` returns `undefined` or `slideIndex-1 < 0`